# Importing .sql.gz file from aws

Tags: backup, mysql, aws

I have a mysql backup in aws and i wanted to import one of the mysql backup file. I am using the command `s3cmd get s3://bucketname/object/local file`. I am getting an error saying `ERROR: Parameter problem: Expecting S3 URI instead of '-'`
. What might be the problem here?

Comment: What is `/local file` here?

Comment: The local file is `31-07-2016 - lymo.sql.gz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-` is a special character, you need to escape your arguments appropriately:

```
s3cmd get "s3://foo.example.com/object" "31-07-2016 - lymo.sql.gz"
```

Comment: The path is `/akshaysolutionbackup/orbit/31-07-2016/31-07-2016 - lymo.sql.gz`. I tried doing `s3cmd get "s3://akshaysolutionbackup/orbit/31-07-2016" "31-07-2016 - lymo.sql.gz"`. Its showing error `s3://akshaysolutionbackup/orbit/31-07-2016 -> 31-07-2016 - lymo.sql.gz  [1 of 1]
ERROR: S3 error: 404 (Not Found):`

Comment: Got it i used ` s3cmd get "s3://akshaysolutionbackup/orbit"/"31-07-2016"/"31-07-2016 - lymo.sql.gz"`